# How to be sure of EF Cores Update() Methods results?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entity-framework-core

The documentation for the `DbContext.Update` method reads as following:

> "Begins tracking the given entity and entries **reachable** from the given entity" ... "For entity types with generated keys if an entity has its primary key value set then it will be tracked in the **Modified** state. If the primary key value is not set then it will be tracked in the **Added** state."

Since I only use Integer Ids, this is actually a build in `AddOrUpdate` method for me. This is obviously a great feature for reasonably complex entity graphs. I can just throw in the root entity into the update method and I'm all fine (aside from deletes).

My problem is the unpredictability. Lets say I have the following entity graph: (everything is a class / entity)

```
Department
   Boss
      Salary
   List<Employee>
      Salary
```

Now I write a simple method in my repository:

```
public void UpdateDepartment(Department dep)
{
    using var context = createContext();

    context.Update(dep);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This is amazing. These 3 lines fire `UPDATE and INSERT` statements for the department, the boss, the salaries and every single Employee into my database. All with 3 lines of code.

What I am afraid of is the future. 3 Months later I realize "woops I forgot the Company". So I update my entity model to look like this:

```
Company
   List<Department>
      Boss
         Salary
      List<Employee>
         Salary
```

If I now call my `UpdateDepartment()` method, its gonna be able to **reach** the Company, since its part of the object graph, and from there every single Department. My `UpdateDepartment` method has become a `UpdateCompanyAndAllDepartments` Method...

Its also not that easy to catch in unit tests. There are several things to keep in mind.

- The test that I write today, while a Company entity does not exist, needs to make sure I do NOT persist the nonexisting Company into the (in memory) database. Company also cannot be null in the department entity that I build for the test...
- So I basically need to assert "Added/Updated" entities Count = X
- This is as far as I know only possible via dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries().Count
- A new problem arises: It's best practice to keep `dbContexts` short lived, but now I need a way to keep it alive longer than the method, so I can check it in the unit test. I'm not sure about adjusting code only for unit tests...

I managed to build something that work, but it requires a solid amount of adjustments and unintuitive code specifically written in a way only for these tests.

Is my worry about Update's side effect just overblown? Should I simply not use it and do everything manually via `dbContext.Entry().State = something`?

Another very simple solution is to adjust my `UpdateDepartment` method with a single line `dep.Company = null;`. This will work, but I have to know exactly where to look and how `Update()` works. A maintenance mess.

Comment: If you do update your entity model in the future to make Company the Aggregate Root, instead of Department, then you would then update Company instead of Department.

Comment: If you do still want Department to be your root object, then it would have a reference to the Company, but the Company should not have a firm reference to a List of Departments.  Company will just be a 'property' of Department, but its owner.

Comment: No ef core entities for a one to many relationship require the child entity to have a reference to the parent entity and the parent entity to have a List<Child>. Maybe not 100% require, but thats how i like to build them and i wouldnt want to lose that.

Comment: Yes, EF requires a reference to the parent entity but that should be virtual and used just for configuring EF.  You should not actually populate that reference in procedural code.  You can't have Parent.Children being a firm reference and Child.Parent being a firm reference at the same time.

Comment: You have to decide whether Company is Aggregate Root and has a firm reference to child Departments or whether Department is the Aggregate Root and has a reference to Company.

Comment: You are right, I would rarely populate Department.Company by myself. I could to it though... and I wouldnt notice.
Its a detail essentially though, what if i decided to add another simple Child Entity to Department but for some reason i do not want that to get saved? It would be persisted by default and i have to notice and remove it again. Also difficult to catch in a test again.

Comment: I think you're disappearing down a rabbit-hole of what-ifs!  Have been there myself!  If you add a "child" entity to Department then you WILL want it to be saved/updated.  That's why its a child.  If its just a 'related' entity then you'd never be changing it in procedural code as part of your Department graph so EF will not make any changes to it.